# Where is Chrome getting this cert?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, macos-catalina

I'm getting a cert error in Chrome hitting an api I'm running locally via Intellij (on a macbook pro). It's not a new project but I was trying to set up self-signed certs and I messed something up.

When I look at the invalid cert in Chrome, it has the name of a cert I deleted. I've searched the drive for the cert (deleted it from Trash), and even grep'd for it. It's not in Intellij that I can tell. I've cleared browser cache and history. Other browsers fail similarly. Not in Intellij's list of certs. It's not in mac's Keychain Access.

I don't see where it's coming from. Is there a way to find out where it's getting the cert from??

Comment: It is a common issue that certs can be cached in different spots (server / client side). One thing you can try to narrow it down is to open the site in another web browser. Does the certificate error still show? If so, the cert is cached on the server. Otherwise, it is being cached in Chrome.

Comment: Firefox errors with: "...invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed." Safari gives TLS warning about the cert being TLS 1.0 or 1.1, and then locks itself up. So likely not in the browser(s). Next I thought keychain, but it's not there or at least, not visible.